# Weird conditional probability question

Tags: probability, statistics

My teacher gave us a problem

Let the random variable X have probability density function

$$
f(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
2(1-x)& \text{if } 0 < x < 1 \\
0& \text{elsewhere}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

He asks us to find the PDF, which I have as:

$$
F(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
0& \text{if } x < 0 \\
2x - x^2& \text{if } 0 < x < 1 \\
1& \text{if } x > 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

He then asks us to find the *median* of X, which I don't know how to do?? I know how to find the mean.

And then he asks: "given $X \geq 0.5$ what is probability that $X$ will be less than $0.75$" and I am not sure how that works? Is that $F(0.75)-F(0.5)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo: you have found the CDF.

---

Hint 1: The median of $X$ is the number $m$ satisfying $P(X \ge m) \ge 1/2$ and $P(X \le m) \ge 1/2$.

> From your CDF computation, this means finding $m \in (0,1)$ such that $1 - (2m - m^2) \ge 1/2$ and $2m - m^2 \ge 1/2$. Actually, there will only be one such $m$, and both inequalities will be equality.

---

Hint 2: 
For your second question, you need to compute
$$P(X \le 0.75 \mid X \ge 0.5).$$
Apply the definition of conditional probability.

> $$P(X \le 0.75 \mid X \ge 0.5) = \frac{P(0.5 \le X \le 0.75)}{P(X \ge 0.5)}$$

Comment: Aha! I understand! Yes, I meant CDF, not PDF! Thank you!!